# Foundation 4 with Rails Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, simple-form

According to the GitHub page, Simple Forms for Rails only works with Foundation 3. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

How can I ensure that the formatting uses Foundation 4? Is there much a difference between Foundation 3 and Foundation's 4 forms?

Answer (score -1):

You can compare the HTML of the forms created on these two pages:

- http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html
- http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/forms.php